# Capitalize a single character in Java

Tags: java, character, uppercase, lowercase

I want to read a single character from the keyboard. If it's a capital letter, convert it to lower case and vice versa.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Nico4
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    char letra;
    boolean mayuscula;

    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese una letra: ");
    letra=in.next().charAt(0);
    mayuscula=Character.isUpperCase(letra);
    if (mayuscula==true) letra=Character.toLowerCase(letra);
    else letra=Character.toUpperCase(letra);
    System.out.println(+letra);
    }
}
```

but I'm not getting the right answer. If I input 'A', it returns 97, but I want 'a'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to print `letra`, why are you printing `+letra`?

Comment: The reason you're getting 97 is that it is the ASCII value of 'a'. Since you introduced the + sign to letra, the compiler treats it as an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `+` when outputting `letra`

```
    System.out.println(letra);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample Code :

```
public class CaptLetter{
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String message = "my message";
    message = Character.toUpperCase(message.charAt(0)) + message.substring(1);
    System.out.println(message); //result like "My message"
    System.out.println(upperCaseWords(sentence)); //result like "Hi Chandru How Are You" 
}

static String sentence = "Hi chandru how are you";
public static String upperCaseWords(String sentence) {
    String words[] = sentence.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim().split(" ");
    String newSentence = "";
    for (String word: words) {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        newSentence = newSentence + ((i == 0) ? word.substring(i, i + 1).toUpperCase() : (i != word.length() - 1) ? word.substring(i, i + 1).toLowerCase() : word.substring(i, i + 1).toLowerCase().toLowerCase() + " ");
    }

    return newSentence;
}}
```

Result:

My message

Hi Chandru How Are You